# Boot Strap Dropdown Menus are not working

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have been messing with this for several days. I'm I missing something? I cannot get the drop down menu to function.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src=" https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-LtrjvnR4Twt/qOuYxE721u19sVFLVSA4hf/rRt6PrZTmiPltdZcI7q7PXQBYTKyf" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Dropdown link
    
  
    
      Action
      Another action
      Something else here

Comment: What does the code for your dropdown menu look like? All the above shows is that you're including the necessary scripts (with perhaps the exception of whether Bootstrap 4.x is compatible with that old a version of jQuery).  We need to see the code for your menu if you want us to troubleshoot your menu.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

make sure that the stylesheet goes in the head and the scripts goes at the end before the closing tag 
Here's the documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/
Quoted from the documentation:

> Copy-paste the stylesheet  into your  before all other stylesheets to load our CSS.
> Many of our components require the use of JavaScript to function. Specifically, they require jQuery, Popper.js, and our own JavaScript plugins. Place the following s near the end of your pages, right before the closing  tag, to enable them. jQuery must come first, then Popper.js, and then our JavaScript plugins.